# AWS Codebuild:YAML File Error message :wrong number of container tags, expected 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run codebuild according to this CFT but getting this error message while building.
The codebuild is simple..reading the source from codecommit and build and store it in S3 bucket
Can anybody point out what is the issue

Error Message:

```
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:12.865253 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:15.073019 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:19.478936 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:19.481311 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src1892399736/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/spring-petclinic
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:19.481832 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src1892399736/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/spring-petclinic/buildspec.yaml
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:19.485543 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/02/29 17:32:19.485556 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: wrong number of container tags, expected 1
```

## My buildspec.yaml file

======================================

:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Create CodeBuild Stack Template

Parameters:
  ApplicationRepoName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the repo which contains Rest Application.
    Default: spring-petclinic
  ArtifactStoreS3Location:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the S3 bucket to store CodePipeline artificat.
    Default: rest-apps-cbd

Resources:
  CodeBuildRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName:
        Fn::Sub: CodeBuildRole-${AWS::StackName}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: /service-role/
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "CodeBuildCICDAccessPolicy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "codecommit:GitPull"
                Resource:
                  - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:codecommit:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApplicationRepoName}
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                Resource:
                  - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/codebuild/*
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:ListBucket"
                Resource:
                  - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-${AWS::Region}-*
                  - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactStoreS3Location}/*
                  - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactStoreS3Location}

  BuildRestAppCFNProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub BuildRestAppCFN-${AWS::StackName}
      Description: Build war file for rest application
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt [ CodeBuildRole, Arn ]
      Artifacts:
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref ArtifactStoreS3Location
        Name: !Sub BuildRestAppCFN-${AWS::StackName}
      Environment:
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/standard:2.0
      Source:
        Location: !Sub https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/${ApplicationRepoName}
        Type: CODECOMMIT
      TimeoutInMinutes: 10      
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub BuildRestAppCFN-${AWS::StackName}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YAML\_FILE\_ERROR Message: Wrong number of container tags, expected 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407882/yaml-file-error-message-wrong-number-of-container-tags-expected-1)

Comment: no..I tried to use it but got some other error

Comment: Why are you using cft? Can't you use yaml file for codebuild and link it to cft? Also is it possible for you to share the yaml generated inside codebuild project. It will be easier to debug!